# AS3 button labels won't change

Tags: actionscript-3, class, label

I'm working with flash CS6 and AIR, I drew a movieclip with some buttons and exported for actionsript, then I wrote down some code that will make some buttons change label. No errors, no warnings, everything works excepts for labels. How can I fix it?

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Downloader extends Sprite{

        public function Downloader() {
            BTNplay.label = 'play';  //this does not work
            BTNplay.y=5;             //this works
        }

    }

}
```

The fact is that I wrote something similar on the main class and it works! How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Did you maybe mean this?

```
BTNPlay.label.text = 'play';
//           ^^^^^
```